# Oracle SQL : Update multirows in oracle using subquery of same table

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this

| Group | Item_No | UL | MODEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 40 | 10 |
| 10 | 1 | 35 | 12 |
| 10 | 1 | 30 | 13 |
| 10 | 2 | NULL | 10 |
| 10 | 2 | NULL | 12 |
| 10 | 2 | NULL | 13 |

I want to update the value of UL where ITEM_NO is 2 from UL of item no =1 minus 5 where Model is same.

So my output table should look like this

| Group | Item_No | UL | MODEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 40 | 10 |
| 10 | 1 | 35 | 12 |
| 10 | 1 | 30 | 13 |
| 10 | 2 | 35 | 10 |
| 10 | 2 | 30 | 12 |
| 10 | 2 | 25 | 13 |

My Query looks like this :

```
Update table t1
   set t1.Ul = ( select t2.ul-5
                   from table t2
                  where t2.item_no =1)
 where t1.model in ( select model
                       from table t2
                      where t2.item_no = 1) , t1. Item_no =2
```

This query returns error as "single-row subquery returns more than one row."
I tried using inner join also but was not able to do it.
Can anyone help how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for below:

```
merge into t1 x
using (select * from t1  where ITEM_NO = 1) y
on (x.M0DEL = y.M0DEL and x.ITEM_NO=2)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET x.UL=Y.UL -5;
```

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:43:20294207843979::NO:::

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1 tt1
set tt1.ul=(select tt2.ul from t1 tt2  where  tt1.model1= tt2.model1 and 
tt2.item_no=2)
where tt1.item_no=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
MERGE INTO table t1
USING table t2
ON (t1.model = t2.model AND t2.Item_No = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t1.UL = t2.UL - 5, t1.Item_No = 2
```

Comment: I don't need to update t1.Item_no =2  should i add' where' instead

Comment: This will update the item_no as well, which is not required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).